# LookUpEdit show deleted item

Tags: c#

In my application i use LookUpEdit to bound data collection.

```
 List<myClass> lst=new List<myClass>();

 void Init()
 { 
     lst.Add(new myClass("One"));
     LookUpEdit.DataSource=lst;
 }


  class myClass()
  {
     public myClass(string name)
     {
         Name=name;
     }

     public ovveride ToString()
     {
         return Name;
     }
 }
```

I choose in LookUpEdit item "One"  and then delete this  item from collection lst. But in LookUpEdit item "One" is shown yet. What is a way to do, that deleted item doesn't show?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the BindingList, which supports those "events", instead of List:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

BindingList<MyClass> lst = new BindingList<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the Row from the `DataTable` containing all the `LookUpEdit` data, you have to then accept changes to apply the deletion. Example assuming your `DataSource` is a `DataTable`:

```
int row = 5; // ROW TO DELETE
BindingSource binding = lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource as BindingSource;
DataTable dt = (binding.DataSource as DataSet).Tables[binding.DataMember];
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
dt.AcceptChanges();
```